# Array saving in Row-Major and finding address of one elements?

Tags: arrays, math, matrix, multidimensional-array, data-structures

I ran into a Multiple Choice Question from previous Entrance Exam on PhD as follows:

if address of A[4][5] be at 1000 in Memory, and method is row-major what is the address of A[2][3] on upper triangle A[1..6, 1..6]  ? each item has 2 bytes.

My solution is :

```
A[4][5]= x + [ (4-1)*6 + (5-1)] * 2 = 1000 ---> x= 1000-40=960.  so
 A[2][3] = 960 + [ (2-1)*6 + (3-1)] * 2 = 976 !!
```

but my solution is not in options in answer sheet. where is wrong? anyone could say?

A) 1016
B) 982
C) 984
D) 1018

Comment: You have just miscalculated the offset (40), which actually is 44: ((4 - 1) * 6 + (5 - 1)) * 2 = (3 * 6 + 4) * 2 = (18 + 4) * 2 = 22 * 2 = *44*, so x = 1000 - *44* = *956*, which is consistent with the answer by Sumeet Singh.

Comment: sorry one mistake. Upper triangle A. I correct it @StefanHaustein

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the starting address to solve this problem, so don't bother what x is.

We are at address 1000 for A[4][5]. The address of elements therefore are:

```
A[4][4] : 998
A[4][3] : 996
A[4][2] : 994
```

Using this simple logic we can find the address of A[2][3].

Now seeing from the available options, the only correct options seems to be B and it seems that **array's index starts from 1 instead of 0** and the main diagonal is included.

So we would be going 9 locations back and hence the correct option is B.

**Explanation**

Because main diagonal is included then we go 1 location back in row 4. 4 locations back in row 3 and 4 locations back in row 2.So total locations went back is 9 and since each element takes 2 bytes the correct answer is **1000 - 9*2 = 982**

Comment: It's 4 locations back (row 4, from [4][5] to [4][1]) + 6 locations back (entire row 3, from [4][1] to [3][1]) + 4 locations back (row 2, from [3][1] to [2][3]) = 4 + 6 + 4 = 14

Comment: @Bob__ Its from [4][5] to [4][0].

Comment: @user3661613 So the main diagonal is not included or is it?

Comment: No, I think from options we mush guess.

Comment: @user3661613 what are the available options?

Comment: How you calculate :) ?

Comment: @user3661613 see my answer.

Comment: @user3661613 like i said you don't need a formula

Comment: my challenge is about formula :)

Comment: is it possible add more clarity?